# How to test a function which loads a DLL

Tags: c++, testing, dll, googletest, googlemock

I have a dll (MyDLL.dll), which I am loading in some class function and then calling a function "DLLProc" from it. Can I write this FuncLoad to be able to test it using a test framework like GTest / GMock...

```
HMODULE module;
SomeInterface service;
.
.
.
void MyClass::FuncLoad()
{
    auto libPath = std::wstring(L"MyDLL.dll");
    module = LoadLibrary(libPath.c_str());

    if (NULL != module)
    {
        ProcType fnObj = (ProcType)GetProcAddress(module, "DLLProc");
        if (NULL != fnObj)
        {
            service = fnObj();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should let testing of the dll function be handled by the dll author. If you want to test MyClass with a `SomeInterface` then you just need to set `service` to your own mocked `SomeInterface`. I hope I understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. Exactly, I just want to test this class function and since "service" is being obtained from DLL, how precisely can I test this function? With mocked SomeInterface, I can test the rest of the class, but not this function?